# PreferenceActivity within TabWidget

Tags: android, tabs, android-preferences, tabwidget, preferenceactivity

Within my program I have a PreferenceActivity as one of my tabs.  I do the following.

```
public class settings extends PreferenceActivity{

// On Create    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
```

This works really well and is slick to help my users find all of their settings.  My problem is I'm starting to get too many settings so I wanted to group them within sub PreferenceScreens.  When I add one of these PreferenceScreens to my xml and navigate my program into it I loss my tabs.  You can back out and everything works fine, but it really messes with the programs whole theme and planned updates. Another option that I'm not sure is possible is a dynamically expandable PreferenceCategory.  I see this done in Dolphin Browser but their settings are also not stock.

Comment: Maybe there's some way to just use the framelayout in preference activity

Comment: Can I maybe use some type of activity manager?

Comment: I gave up on this and just put preference screens in.  It isn't as smooth for the user but I had to do it.